# Connecting multiple Net Labels to same Net Wire

Tags: schematics, altium, gpio

I am using `Altium Designer 17`. My schematics is `Hierarchical` and divided into multiple sheets.

Few sheets have microprocessor stuff and other schematics have sensors in it. I have to connect sensor's pins to GPIO pins of the processor.

Sheets in which GPIOs are taken out from schematics symbol of the processor uses conventions like `GPIO_PIN_180` as `Net Labels` and sheets which have sensors uses names corresponding to the functions of that pin as `Net Labels` (For example, ACC_INT is a interrupt pin of accelerometer).

Now, I want to connect two different net labels but they give me warning/error like `Nets with Multiple names`. I know how to disable that warning or error but I don't want to disable it as it helped us in the past to find few bugs. I want to know Industry standard to handle such situations to make my schematics readable and acceptable to other experienced designers. [image]

Comment: You need to think seriously about why you're assigning two different names to the net in the first place. What does this actually accomplish for you?

Comment: Few sheets which are at microprocessor hierarchy uses names for GPIO corresponding to the pin numbers. However, sheets having sensors requires names corresponding to their functions as it makes them more readable. I am planning to make one sheet which will tie two different net labels together.

Comment: Yes, you said all of that in the question. I repeat: *What does this actually accomplish for you?* Why not carry the sensor signal names all of the way to the pins of the microprocessor? Those are the names that are most relevant to your actual application.

Comment: To make sheets reusable and independent of other sheets. I can implement what you have suggested if there isn't any other way to properly implement it?

Comment: In that case, reusable sheets need to be *hierarchical* sheets. Does Altium throw an error if you connect a net with one name to a hierarchical sheet port with a different name? I've never used Altium myself, but this worked fine in other software I've used.

Comment: Altium will not throw an error if you connect a port with some name to a net with another name at the hierarchical level, *provided* you disable "Allow ports to name nets".

Comment: There is no reason to not have a hierarchical sheet with the processor IO pin numbers (as an example) and then connect to a sensor net at the next level up. This means there is *no* confusion about what the net is supposed to be accomplishing at higher levels and removes any desire to put two names on a single net, which is a *really* bad practice anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know is a net-tie. For example to connect Power_GND with Ana_GND in a defined way.